# reading Managed Packages via MetadataApi

Tags: apex, managed-package, metadata-api, metadata

is it possible to read infromation about sObjects that are from managed packages?

I am using MetadataService from this [git](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). [Class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls)

I am very eager to use this method from class above, but is it even possible?

```
public MetadataService.IReadResult readMetadata(String type_x,String[] fullNames) {
        MetadataService.readMetadata_element request_x = new MetadataService.readMetadata_element();
        request_x.type_x = type_x;
        request_x.fullNames = fullNames;
        MetadataService.IReadResponseElement response_x;
        Map<String, MetadataService.IReadResponseElement> response_map_x = new Map<String, MetadataService.IReadResponseElement>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
 request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          '',
          SOAP_M_URI,
          'readMetadata',
          SOAP_M_URI,
          'readMetadataResponse',
          'MetadataService.read' + type_x + 'Response_element'}
 );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.getResult();
    }
```

There is some code that i was trying. Both sObjects are from managed packages.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
TranslationService.ValidationResult validLabels = new TranslationService.ValidationResult();
List<String> co = new List<String>();
co.add('trailheadapp__Badge__c');
co.add('et4ae5__AggregateLink__c');
List<MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation> customObjectTranslations = (List<MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation>) service.readMetadata('CustomObjectTranslation', co).getRecords();
for (MetadataService.CustomObjectTranslation cot : customObjectTranslations) {
    if (cot.fields != null) {
        for(MetadataService.CustomFieldTranslation customFieldTranslation : cot.fields) {
            
            String fieldName = customFieldTranslation.name.substring(0, customFieldTranslation.name.length() - 3);
            system.debug('CustomField.' + cot.fullName + '.' + fieldName + '.FieldLabel');
            system.debug('CustomField.' + cot.fullName + '.' + fieldName + '.HelpText');
            
            if(customFieldTranslation.picklistValues != null){
                for(MetadataService.PicklistValueTranslation picklistValueTranslation : customFieldTranslation.picklistValues){
                    system.debug('PicklistValue.' + cot.fullName + '.' + fieldName + '.' + picklistValueTranslation.masterLabel);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        system.debug('Doesnt exists');
    }
}
```

Comment: What objects? sObjects? Everything in the package? There may be different ways to approach this problem depending on your goals.

Comment: If by "objects" you **do** mean SObjects then you can read the details locally using the Schema API in Apex, or you can use the Metadata API if you want to get the details remotely. After all, the latter is what IDEs do in order to support things like auto-completion, help text etc. for both packaged and subscriber object model details.

Comment: At this point I'm focusing on sObjects, specifically I'm concerned with what types of fields go on them, what picklist values, what record types, etc. If there is another solution, I'm interested in learning about it. I've been struggling with this for a long time and I can't get through it

Comment: @PhilW I have tried to get this data via MetadataApi, but without any results.

Comment: Are you requesting namespaced object names?

Comment: BTW: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm

Comment: Ive added some code that i was using.

Comment: What is the context of this code? If it is Apex, use the Schema API. Please clarify. Looking at the first block of code you have `response_x` and `response_map_x` which is populated using the `response_x`. However, `response_x` is not initialized (so is null) when added to the map. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: First block of code is code from MetadataService class that i took from github. From what I understand it is a method responsible for sending a request with objects about which we want to receive information. I did not create this method. The second part is my anonymous code, which I used to show the logic behind calling the method read from MetadataService. I use MetadataApi, because I have to not only read the information about the object, but also I have to create the translation for them, but this is not my problem.

Comment: What is interesting, creating the translation for e.g. sObject trailheadapp__Badge__c works without an error, but calling the method responsible for reading the information about it does not.

Comment: I am only interested in information about what kind of fields the object has and what their names are.

Comment: I can also add, that reading metadata for e.g. Account object, or any other custom object created by me works well and returns desired results